# react-native check re-install by persistent storage

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have question about saving data into persistent storage (on Android),
I want to check is user re-install this app on same device or not.
I try [react-native-sensitive-info](https://github.com/mCodex/react-native-sensitive-info) and [react-native-keychain](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-keychain) to save data to keychain on IOS and SharedPreferences on android.
IOS is working fine but on Android the data was erased which I can't check user has re-installed app or not.

On file AndroidManifest.xml I set

```
tools:replace="android:allowBackup" 
android:allowBackup="true"
```

but it still not working. Do you have any suggestion?